# Increasing fastcgi_read_timeout for pages under specific folder

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I would like to increase the `fastcgi_read_timeout` setting for specific magento pages using the nginx config, but cannot seem to get it to override the php-fpm `request_terminate_timeout` setting of 30s.

```
location ~ .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    expires        off;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    location = /admin/ { fastcgi_read_timeout 10800; }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can increase the timeout for just the admin directory?

Comment: Isn't `request_terminate_timeout` related to PHP-FPM settings rather than nginx? Its default value is 0, it is used only when `max_execution_time` doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Updated an answer, please give some feedback if this approach works (I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
map $request_uri $timeout {
    ~/admin/    10800;
    default     60;
}
server {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_read_timeout $timeout;
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also try something like

```
map $request_uri $timeout {
    ~/admin/    10800;
    default     60;
}
map $request_uri $maxexec {
    ~/admin/    "max_execution_time=10800; request_terminate_timeout=10800";
    default     "";
}
server {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_read_timeout $timeout;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE $maxexec if_not_empty;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE $maxexec if_not_empty;
        ...
    }
}
```

**Update**

Ok, since `fastcgi_read_timeout` doesn't take variable as a value, you can try to split PHP handler in two (**exactly in this order**):

```
server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/admin/.+\.php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 10800s;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "max_execution_time=10800; request_terminate_timeout=10800";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "max_execution_time=10800; request_terminate_timeout=10800";
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nick Updated once more, no `map` directive anymore since we have two separate `location` blocks.

Comment: @Nick Looks like this way you can change only `max_execution_time`, `request_terminate_timeout` could be specified only in PHP-FPM pool configuration.